# Trouble with Raylib install on Arch Linux

Tags: c++, raylib

I am learning Raylib game library, but in the "First Person Maze" example the images cannot be found, for example:

```
`Image imMap = LoadImage("cubicmap.png");`
```

returns a File not Found by the compiler/linker, it´s the same with the other image. I am using CodeLite IDE, but I don't know how to add assets, right now I have them in a virtual folder named "resources".

Any help would be nice, I have googled the problem but I can't find anything. But now I don't know what's wrong because I have compiled the library with make and make install and also added Raylib package from Arch Linux and I can't even run the *My first window* example from the site.

Comment: The example has the folder name 'resources'  prepended to the file name. You might want to try the same.

Comment: I have tried that but in the console, when i run the program it says fail to open file, same thing for the other texture and i can only see a new window with the FPS count running, (and then it stops)

Comment: Did you make sure that the path of your assets is relative to where the executable will be built and ran?

Comment: Vaillancourt you were right the folders in CodeLite are really virtual, you have to make shure the file is actually there

Comment: You might want to write an answer with all of this to help future visitors :)

Answer (score 1):

As Vaillancourt said, in CodeLite IDE when you create a virtual folder it's really virtual, you have to make sure your files are actually in a folder in your project, otherwise your files won't be loaded.

Comment: Often, the "folders" you see in your IDE are there just to organize the code in the project, they are not necessarily related to how the files are laid out in the file system (in Visual Studio, those "folders" are even called "filters" to avoid confusion, even if the icon is the classic "folder" icon). Also, your assets don't generally belong to the IDE's "folder" structure. The compiler and linkers are unaware of those assets, they're only important when the game is executed.